# Odoo: How to rename "New" label, in odoo module, in new object form?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

[image]

when i create a new meeting in calendar module, it shows like "New"
i want rename that label, for example, to "New meeting"
is it possible? and where can i find this place in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `New` value is defined in the basic model of the form view. To change it you can override the [getName](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9c19460ce7fb1a16cfeed607e474e273f5ce690b/addons/web/static/src/legacy/js/views/basic/basic_model.js#L716-L726) function like the following:

```js
import BasicModel from 'web.BasicModel';
import core from 'web.core';

var _t = core._t;

BasicModel.include({
    getName: function (id) {
        var record = this.localData[id];
        var returnValue = this._super(id);
        if ( returnValue === _t("New") && record.model == 'calendar.event') {
            return _t('New meeting');
        } else {
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
});
```

You need to add the file under the `assets` entry in the `__manifest__.py` file.

```
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        '{module_name}/static/src/js/basic_model.js',
    ],
}
```

***Edit:***

For more details on how to add the js file to the manifest, check the [assets](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/reference/frontend/assets.html) documentation.

Comment: i try to add a new .js file in module, register it in manifest and do actions in your guide, but odoo crashes. I find way maybe not right but working. I go in base file in odoo\addons\web\static\src\legacy\js\views\basic\basic_model.js, and change some code:
  
`/** return returnValue || _t("New"); */  
        if (returnValue == '' && record.model == 'calendar.event') {  
            return 'New meeting';
        } else {
            return returnValue || _t("New");
        }`
and it works.
Thanks.

Comment: Set the file path relative to the module name. Use the above path if you created the js (`basic_model.js`) file inside the `static/src/js folder`